# Moving large QEMU image files from damaged HDD to new drive impossible

Tags: hard-drive, dd, qemu, copy

Hmmm... I have a very strange thing at hand:

Due to a system's HDD wearout failure (defective blocks) we obviously had to replace the HDD. Everything worked well until we started to move two files of an existing VM of 16.9 (overlay image) and 35.7 GB (base image) to the new HDD. The base image (35.7 GB) moved OK while the copy process of the overlay image stopped after 13 GB with a generic I/O error. `DD` and `qemu-img commit {overlay image}` also produced a "generic I/O error" with no further details. `pv` reports a read error.

Putting the old HDD back into the system as an additional drive and subsequently starting the VM from the old HDD works fine, i. e. the VM starts as expected and appears to be fully functional with no errors so far which leads to the conclusion that the file in question should be undamaged.

How do we move the two files to the new drive?

Comment: You can always try `ddrescue`. Depending on the condition of your HDD, it might take a few tries (`ddrescue` will resume from the last block read).

Comment: It's getting even more weird - I forced `pv` to produce a copy and skip the damaged blocks. This copy is executable as well and the VM appears to work without errors so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright `pv` did the trick with option `-EE`